# Is there a way to remove just a field name from json object generate through Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, api

I am developing a sample application to learn Spring. I want my service to return results in the below format.

```
{
  [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "age": "25"
    },
    {
      "name": "Jack",
      "age": "20"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have designed a class like this to store data about a person.

```
class Person {
  String name;
  String age;
  //getters and setters
}
```

Another class that hold the array of Person like

```
class Result {
  ArrayList<Person> result = new ArrayList();

  void addPerson(Person p) {
      result.add(p);
  }
  //getter for result
}
```

When I make a call for my API, I am getting the result in the following format.

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "age": "25"
    },
    {
      "name": "Jack",
      "age": "20"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I make the "result" string go away from the result? Have I designed it wrong?

Thank you

Comment: You can't. What you want to obtain (in the first example) is not legal json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make array as root element using @JsonValue

```
class Result {
  @JsonValue
  ArrayList<Person> result = new ArrayList();

  ...
}
```

output json:

```
  [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "age": "25"
    },
    {
      "name": "Jack",
      "age": "20"
    }
  ]
```

your json {[...]} is not valid json